position: fixed does not work on ios 18 along with container requests
I wanted to create a sticky background so that it doesn't scroll along with the page on the iPhone 15 Pro with iOS 18, but there was a problem - if the class has a container with the page/inline-size property set, the position:fixed stops working.
Here is my code in scss.
.page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-inline-size: 320px;
  min-block-size: 100dvb;
  position: relative;
  // background-color: var(--color-bg, #fff);
  // background-image: var(--gradient-light-scheme);
  // background-attachment: fixed;
  font-family: var(--main-font, 'inter-variable', sans-serif);
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-main);
  color: var(--font-main-color, #000);
  container: page / inline-size;

  &::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
    block-size: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--color-bg, #fff);
    background-image: var(--gradient-light-scheme);
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

I want the page's background to not move with it, but remain fixed.
